# An example on Vakil FOAG : $27/4$ is function on $\operatorname{Spec}{\Bbb{Z}} - \{[(2)],[(7)]\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was reading Vakil's FOAG, in section 4.3.6 there is an example which says:

$27/4$ is function on $\operatorname{Spec}{\Bbb{Z}} - \{[(2)],[(7)]\}$ with value at $[(5)]$ is $2/(-1) = -2$.

---

I can't really understand why, and I am not sure if my understanding is correct?

"function" here means elements in $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}{\Bbb{Z}}}(U)$ here $\operatorname{Spec}{\Bbb{Z}} - \{[(2)],[(7)]\} = D(2)\cap D(7) = D(14)$ therefore we can translate it to $27/4$ is an element of $\Bbb{Z}_{14} $ which holds true since $$27/4 = 27\cdot 7^2/14^2$$

Is my understanding correct?

for the second question I need to get value of $27/4$ at $[(5)]$, that is image of $27/4$ under the following map:

$$\Bbb{Z}_{14} \to \mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec}{\Bbb{Z}},[(5)]} \cong\Bbb{Z}_{(5)} \to \Bbb{Z}_{(5)}/\frak{m}_5 $$, however, I don't understand how to compute this, why its value is $-2$ at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stalk of $27/4$ at the residue field of $(5)$ is what you get when you reduce $27/4$ mod $5$. Since $4^{-1} \mod 5 = 4$ , it's $27 * 4 \mod 5 = 3 = -2$.

Comment: Oh thank you I see the key point is $1/4 = 4$ in $\Bbb{Z_{(5)}}/ ((5)\Bbb{Z}_{(5)})$ which is because $4-1/4 = 15/4$ we see $5\mid 15$ therefore $1/4  = 4$ in it